# i keep getting this error ( a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char" ) how can i solve it?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game where the player will be facing the computer in C but I'm having issues assigning `CheckWinner()` to `winner` in line 28 and 35, is there any solution?

This is the message I keep getting: `a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char").

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

char board[3][3];
const char PLAYER = 'X';
const char COMPUTER = 'O';

void resetBoard();
void printBoard();
int checkFreeSpaces();
void PlayerMove();
void ComputerMove();
void CheckWinner();
void printWinner(char);

int main()
{
   char winner = ' ';

   resetBoard();
   while (winner == ' ' && checkFreeSpaces() != 0)
   {
      printBoard();

      PlayerMove();
      winner = CheckWinner();
      if (winner != ' ' || checkFreeSpaces() == 0)
      {
         break;
      }

      ComputerMove();
      winner = CheckWinner();
      if (winner != ' ' || checkFreeSpaces() == 0)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   printBoard();
   printWinner(winner);

   return 0;
}

void resetBoard()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
         board[i][j] = ' ';
      }
   }
}

void printBoard()
{
   printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
   printf("\n---|---|---\n");
   printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
   printf("\n---|---|---\n");
   printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
   printf("\n");
}

int checkFreeSpaces()
{
   int freeSpaces = 9;
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
         if (board[i][j] != ' ')
         {
            freeSpaces--;
         }
      }
   }
   return freeSpaces;
}

void PlayerMove()
{
   int x;
   int y;

   do
   {
      printf("Enter row #(1-3): ");
      scanf("%d", &x);
      x--;
      printf("Enter column #(1-3): ");
      scanf("%d", &y);
      y--;

      if (board[x][y] != ' ')
      {
         printf("Invalid move\n");
      }
      else
      {
         board[x][y] = PLAYER;
         break;
      }
   } while (board[x][y] != ' ');
}

void ComputerMove()
{
   // creates a seed based on curent time
   srand(time(0));
   int x;
   int y;

   if (checkFreeSpaces() > 0)
   {
      do
      {
         x = rand() % 3;
         y = rand() % 3;

      } while (board[x][y] != ' ');
      board[x][y] = COMPUTER;
   }
   else
   {
      printWinner(' ');
   }
}

void CheckWinner()
{
   // check rows
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][0] == board[i][2])
      {
         return board[i][0];
      }
   }

   // check columns
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[0][i] == board[2][i])
      {
         return board[0][i];
      }
   }

   // check diagonals
   if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2])
   {
      return board[0][0];
   }

   if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[2][0])
   {
      return board[0][2];
   }

   return ' ';
}

void printWinner(char winner)
{
   if (winner == PLAYER)
   {
      printf("YOU WIN!");
   }
   else if (winner == COMPUTER)
   {
      printf("YOU LOSE!");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("IT'S A TIE!");
   }
}
```

Comment: your CheckWinner function returns a char, then: `char CheckWinner();`

Comment: Did you mean to define `CheckWinner` as `char CheckWinner`, not `void CheckWinner`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `CheckWinner()` should be declared and defined as `char`, not `void`.

Note also these remarks:

- you should output a trailing newline in function `printWinner()`.
- the test in the main loop `while (winner == ' ' && checkFreeSpaces() != 0)` is redundant.  You should use a for ever loop instead: `for (;;)`
- same problem in `PlayerMove()`: the `do` / `while` loop test is redundant, just use a for ever loop `for (;;)`.
- you should check for `scanf()` conversion failures to avoid undefined behavior on invalid and missing input.
- it is not necessary for `checkFreeSpaces()` to count the number of free spaces, returning `1` or `0` as a boolean indicator would suffice and be more efficient.
- **[major]** the function `CheckWinner()` will return `' '` as a winning party if there is an alignment of 3 empty spaces.  This is incorrect and may prevent proper detection of the winning party.  You should modify the function to check if a given party has won, passed as an argument.
- the pseudo random number generator should be initialized once in the `main()` function.  Reinitializing it for every computer move is wasteful and introduces a strong bias.
- you check for `checkFreeSpaces()` in `ComputerMove` but not in `PlayerMove()`. Given how these functions are called, there should always be at least one free space.  Yet it seems useful to check for empty spaces in these functions, return `0` if the move cannot be done and simplify the `main()` function loop.
- you should check that `x` and `y` are in the range `1` to `3`, otherwise invalid values will cause out of bounds accesses with undefined behavior.
- the array `board` should not be a global object, defining it in `main` and passing it as an argument is a better approach.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const char PLAYER = 'X';
const char COMPUTER = 'O';

void resetBoard(char board[3][3]);
void printBoard(const char board[3][3]);
int checkFreeSpaces(const char board[3][3]);
int playerMove(char board[3][3]);
int computerMove(char board[3][3]);
int checkWinner(const char board[3][3], char player);
void printWinner(char winner);

int main(void) {
    char board[3][3];
    char winner = ' ';

    // creates a seed based on curent time
    srand(time(0));

    resetBoard(board);
    for (;;) {
        printBoard(board);
        playerMove(board);
        if (checkWinner(board, PLAYER)) {
            winner = PLAYER;
            break;
        }
        if (!checkFreeSpaces(board)) {
            break;
        }

        computerMove(board);
        if (checkWinner(board, COMPUTER)) {
            winner = COMPUTER;
            break;
        }
        if (!checkFreeSpaces(board)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printBoard(board);
    printWinner(winner);

    return 0;
}

void resetBoard(char board[3][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(const char board[3][3]) {
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
}

int checkFreeSpaces(const char board[3][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == ' ')
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getNumber(const char *prompt, int min, int max) {
    for (;;) {
        int val;  // value read from the user
        int rc;   // scanf return code
        int c;    // variable to store bytes read from stdin
        printf("Enter %s #(%d-%d): ", prompt, min, max);
        // read a number from the user
        rc = scanf("%d", &val);
        // read and discard the rest of the input line
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (rc == 1) {
            if (val >= min && val <= max)
                return val;
            printf("invalid value %d, must be between %d and %d\n", val, min, max);
        } else
        if (rc == 0) {
            printf("invalid input, must be a number\n");
        } else {
            printf("unexpected end of file, exiting\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int playerMove(char board[3][3]) {
    if (!checkFreeSpaces(board))
        return 0;

    for (;;) {
        int x = getNumber("row", 1, 3) - 1;
        int y = getNumber("column", 1, 3) - 1;

        if (board[x][y] != ' ') {
            printf("Invalid move\n");
        } else {
            board[x][y] = PLAYER;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int computerMove(char board[3][3]) {
    if (!checkFreeSpaces(board))
        return 0;

    for (;;) {
        // try random cells until an available one is found
        int x = rand() % 3;
        int y = rand() % 3;
        if (board[x][y] == ' ') {
            board[x][y] = COMPUTER;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int checkWinner(const char board[3][3], char player) {
    // check rows and columns
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[i][0] == player && board[i][1] == player && board[i][2] == player)
            return 1;
        if (board[0][i] == player && board[1][i] == player && board[2][i] == player)
            return 1;
    }

    // check diagonals
    if (board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player)
        return 1;
    if (board[0][2] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void printWinner(char winner) {
    if (winner == PLAYER) {
        printf("YOU WIN!\n");
    } else
    if (winner == COMPUTER) {
        printf("YOU LOSE!\n");
    } else {
        printf("IT'S A TIE!\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code there is two mistakes of same type:
1st you declared `void checkWinner()` at function declaration and function definition, but trying to return a `char` value from `char board[][]` array which contains character type values.

**SOLUTION:-**
You need to change the `void checkWinner()` to `char checkWinner()` it will work fine.